# New Earth Layer in My Tracks app - Android Dev

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-earth

In the last version of the Android App "My Tracks" (v2.0.11) there is a new Layer called "Earth" in the embedded Map (the map displays GPX tracks) :

[Layer Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji2LM.png)

This new Layer presents the GPX track in Earth mode (3D) :

[Embedded Earth display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFNN8.jpg)

I found some old code source of the app and they used the Google Maps API V2 to display the track with the 4 built-in options :

- "Normal"
- "Hybrid"
- "Satellite"
- "Terrain"

I also use Google Maps API V2 in my app, how can I add the "Earth" layer ?

I updated all libraries and I think there isn't any new layer option (MAP_TYPE_NORMAL, MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE, MAP_TYPE_HYBRID, MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN). Maybe they don't use Google Maps Api V2 to display the Earth map...

Currently, I open Earth via an Intent but I would like to manage all the layers the same way.

Any clue will be very appreciated.